# How to count the number of parent record column strings per row in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to show a count of the number of parent records per record. all parent records have the same "REC" string, so I was going to count those, but I am unable to get it to work right now. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Sample Image] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7zCH.png)

I tried this but it didn't work but I think I am close. I am getting 0 for all the results:

Results=
VAR _rows = {[parent 1], [parent 2], [parent 3], [parent 4], [parent 5], [parent 6], [parent 7], [parent 8], [parent 9]}
VAR _count = COUNTROWS (Filter (_rows, [Value] = "REC"))
Return IF (_count > 0, _count, 0)

I also tried this but also did not work. I got the error message: "A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected"

Results 2 =
VAR _rows = {[parent 1], [parent 2], [parent 3], [parent 4], [parent 5], [parent 6], [parent 7], [parent 8], [parent 9]}
VAR _count = COUNTROWS(FILTER('Table - Name',CONTAINSSTRING(_rows, "REC")))
RETURN _count

Comment: in PowerQuery, select the first column, and unpivot all the other columns. Then this is trivial.